# Info tab does not appear for custom Avplayer on tvos?

Tags: tvos

I am using avplayerItem.externalmetadata property. Everything is working fine with AVPlayerViewController. But in my case, I am using AVplayer object to play the content. But then I dont see Info section on my AppleTV.

Please help/suggest..

Answer (score 0):

AVPlayerViewController is built on top of AVPlayer. That info section at the top, together with the progress bar and their associated actions is exactly what AVPlayerViewController is.

When using directly AVPlayer you only get a bare minimum player without any extra. If you need the rest of the elements you have to either use AVPlayerViewController or to implement your custom solution for that on top of AVPlayer.